# STM32U5 SCL line stays low and hangs

Tags: stm32, i2c, programming, digital-communications

I have two STM32L0 (slaves) and STM32U585 (master) MCUs. I have no issue when Slave transmits data to Master, but if Master transmits signal to Slave, it sends all the 9 clock pulses with address bits, and then SCL remains low while SDA returns high.

I see my code hangs at this point and never continues:

```
  */* Write data to TXDR */
  hi2c->Instance->TXDR = *hi2c->pBuffPtr;*
```

This is located in HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit() function.
It seems to be a common issue with either STM32 or HAL libraries. Wondering if anyone could find a fix for that.

Comment: The most likely cause of a hang at a line of code like that is a HardFault occurring due to  either `hi2c->pBuffPtr` having been loaded with an invalid pointer value, or `hi2c` itself being invalid. What does your `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit()` call look like?

Comment: Can you explain how the slave can send data to the master if the master has been corrupted.

Comment: @brhans I don't know if you have experience with STM32 HAL Drivers. The command to call is:
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c3, (uint16_t)I2C_ADDRESS, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, 2, TimeOut); 
Which I transfer 2 bytes. But the numbers of bytes did not change the situation.
And on the Slave side I have:
HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, 2, TimeOut);

Comment: @Andyaka: Sending data from Slave to Master was OK. Imagine above commands but changing Transmit with Receive and vice versa. My problem is sending data from Master to Slave.

Comment: A slave can only send to a master when requested by the master and, if master transmissions are corrupted, how can this happen?

Comment: So either `aRxBuffer` is a pointer with an invalid value or it's not a pointer at all, or you've failed to properly initialize `hi2c3` and its `Instance` field is invalid.

Comment: The fact that you're type-casting `aRxBuffer` as a `uint8_t *` is suspicious. If `aRxBuffer` were the correct type that probably wouldn't be necessary. Perhaps you should be making the call with `&aRxBuffer` instead.